# Skillbuilders save before exit with Skillbuilders modal page

Tags: plugins, oracle-apex

I am having troubles trying to understand how to use "Save before Exit" plugin with the Modal Page plugin in Oracle ApEx v4.1.1.

I basically would like to know how to attached the 'X' close button to the "Save before Exit" plugin when a user makes a change to a select list or text area field on the page (I also have  classes associated to these fields), used within the modal page?

Here are links to the two plugins that I am trying to link together:

http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=46685:MODAL_PAGE:0

http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=46685:SAVE_BEFORE_EXIT:0:::::

Comment: you want to check if there are unsaved changes when the user closes the modal page by clicking the modal dialog close button?

Comment: Hi Tom - yes this is correct. Just unsure how to capture this if the user presses the close button by accident let's say. Any ideas? Have you used these plugins at all? THanks.

Comment: I'm familiar with the plugins, i've used the modal one a lot. Save before exit not so much. I've now spent quite some time on trying to nicely integrate both, but it's proving to be a serious PITA.  Most of the hurt is because of how save before exit works: it is an onbeforeunload event. It does fire in FF, but only late after the facts: colorbox (modal popup) has already removed the markup at that point. I'll post some of my findings/ideas later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important note:** i tested this plugin with the latest version available: 3.0.2. The change detection routine there is `modificationDetected`, where in 3.0.0 it was `changeDetected`! Check which version you use!

---

When i have to integrate things like these, i want to avoid altering provided code such as the plugin code. Doing this will break your stuff if you don't remember in the future and install a new version (unless you're actually fixing something of course).

Create a dynamic action on the page that calls the modal dialog, fire on load:

```
var default_colorbox_close = $.colorbox.close;
$.colorbox.close = function(){
   iframejQ = $("iframe").get(0).contentWindow.apex.jQuery;
   iframeDoc = iframejQ($("iframe").get(0).contentWindow.document);

   apex.debug("Colorbox close attempt - check changes");
   var hasChange = iframeDoc.apex_save_before_exit("modificationDetected");
   apex.debug('Modal contains changes: '+hasChange);

   if(hasChange){
      $( "<div title='Unsaved changes!'>There are unsaved changes. Close the popup anyway?</div>" ).dialog({
         resizable: false,
         height:140,
         modal: true,
         stack: true,
         zIndex: 9999,
         buttons: {
            "Don't close": function() {
               $(this).dialog( "close" );               
            },
            "Close": function() {               
               iframeDoc.apex_save_before_exit("disableWarning")
               default_colorbox_close();
               $(this).dialog( "close" );
            }
         }
      });
   } else {
      apex.debug('Close modal with default colorbox close');
      default_colorbox_close();
   };
};
```

The save before exit plugin works by using the browser `window.onbeforeunload` event. It does trigger when the popup is closed (at least in FF it does), but by then it is way too late: the popup is gone and the markup too.
My first thought was to simply tap that onbeforeunload event by redirecting the page to a generic page which would hold onload code to close the popup. The onbeforeunload would spring in action as soon as the redirect would be attempted. There would be no dynamic action or plugin altering. But oh well, i decided against that. (Note though: most of the code in this snippet would have to be reused in that case too, save change detection and dialog).
Instead i choose to check for changes in the iframe document when a close event happens, and display a dialog, which can be modified too, and clearly indicates that you are performing an action on the popup and not on "the page" (which could be interpreted as the parent page of the modal).

So what is needed is to catch the modal popup close event. Note that the plugin is based of the jQuery Colorbox plugin. The Skillbuilder modal does not provide a pre-close event and can not without altering the colorbox plugin.
Colorbox provides a close option in the form of the "X" and also the ESC-key. I want to catch both(/all).
I didn't opt for unbinding the click on the X and binding a new click.

- what i did first is save the default colorbox close event, and
  then override the default.

  ```
   var default_colorbox_close = $.colorbox.close;
   $.colorbox.close = function(){
  ```
- Next up: this piece of code will get the jQuery instance of the modal
  page. I then fetch the document element of the page with this jquery
  instance

  ```
   iframejQ = $("iframe").get(0).contentWindow.apex.jQuery;
   iframeDoc = iframejQ($("iframe").get(0).contentWindow.document);
  ```
- Next up is checking the iframe (modal popup) for changes

  ```
   var hasChange = iframeDoc.apex_save_before_exit("modificationDetected");
  ```
- So if the page has changes, a warning has to be displayed. I do this
  by using jQuery-UI Dialog. It will have "Unsaved changes!" as title,
  and 2 buttons ("Don't close" and "Close").    When closing, the save
  before exit plugin has to have its default warning disabled! If not,
  you'd still get prompted by the onbeforeunload message!   Then the
  colorbox has to be closed (which will remove the iframe).   Finally
  the dialog (prompt) has to be closed.

  ```
    if(hasChange){
       $( "<div title='Unsaved changes!'>There are unsaved changes. Close the popup anyway?</div>" ).dialog({
          resizable: false,
          height:140,
          modal: true,
          stack: true,
          zIndex: 9999,
          buttons: {
             "Don't close": function() {
                $(this).dialog( "close" );               
             },
             "Close": function() {               
                iframeDoc.apex_save_before_exit("disableWarning")
                default_colorbox_close();
                $(this).dialog( "close" );
             }
          }
       });
  ```
- If there are no changes, then the modal can simply be closed.

  ```
    } else {
       apex.debug('Close modal with default colorbox close');
       default_colorbox_close();
    };
  ```

Hope some of that sticks ;)

**Example on http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=11128:1**

---

**Edit:**
And some big thanks to Dan McGhan for helping in the OTN thread :)
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2434115&tstart=0

Comment: Hey Tom, I really appreciate your effort in helping me out. I will try and absorb what you have presented and come back to you. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey tonsils, i altered the code a lot, it should be a lot easier to test now!

Comment: Hey Tom, thanks for the update and the example - exactly what I was after. One thing though Tom that I have noticed is that if I edit an employee, make a change to their name say, press on the 'X' button, I get your message "There are unsaved changes. Close the popup anyway?", I then say "Don't Close", press the "Save" button on the modal popup, then get the message from Dan's save before exit plugin which then brings the main parent window contents into the modal pop-up. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, that'll be bad setup on my part really. The save before exit selector for which elements to ignore is set to the standard `:button`. However, the "buttons" in the theme are no html buttons, but anchors styled as such. That means you will get the save before exit popup and a redirect to the "master page" (branch generated). Again, bad setup on my part: on save there should be a redirect to same page with success message, and the auto-close selector of the modal popup set to the success message element.

Comment: I fixed up the example. I was too giddy yesterday to notice this ;)

Comment: No problems Tom - will check it out and apply to my app. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Hi Tom - all working perfectly based on updated example. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add something to the answer. I've noticed that the items that changed are not highlighted.  So I've added this line to the "Don't Close" right before closing the dialog box.

```
iframeDoc.apex_save_before_exit('modifiedItems', {highlight:true});
```

And it highlights the items as it should!